# how to access the json key using python json?

Tags: python, json

How can i access the `bg` key in the following json structure in python ?

```json
{
    "window" : [
        {
            "bg" : "#ffffff",
            "title" : "Tkinter Design Light Theme"
        }
    ],
    "button" : [
        {
            "bg" : "#8685EF",
            "fg" : "#ffffff",
            "activebackground" : "#ffffff",
            "activteforeground" : "#E3E0F3",
            "font" : "monopace",
            "boderwidth" : "0"

        }
    ]
}
```

i tried using

```py
with open('./light.json','r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    color = data['button']
bg = color['bg']
```

but it didn't work out for me

Thanks.

Comment: Try using ``json.loads(file.read())``, not ``json.load(file)``

Comment: already tried it but it didn't work out for me

Comment: @ThisIs why? Json.load() can handle a file perfectly fine - no need to use json.loads() on a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `button` value is a `list` of `dict`, you should get the first element of the list like this
`bg = color[0]['bg]`

Answer (score 1):

JSON load deserialises the contents of the file, taken in as the first argument, into a Python object. Here that object is a dictionary. You can get the value associated with the `'button'` key, which returns a *list of dictionaries*. You therefore need to access the list by using index 0 before getting the value of the key `color`.

```py
with open('./light.json','r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
color = data['bg']
bg = color[0]['bg']  # change here, index list before accessing dictionary
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

`data['button']` is a list of dictionaries. You have to iterate over it and print the required value. - `bg`

```
import json

with open('./light.json','r') as file:
    data = json.loads(file.read())
    color = data['button']

for item in color:
    print(item['bg'])
```